# How to edit package name in manifest of android apk

Tags: android, manifest, apk, filenames

i want to **launch same application twice** on my phone so i did google and got that i need to **change package name** so i used ***apktool*** for this and decompile my apk and change package name in manifest file but when i try to rebuild it gives me some error........!! now i don't know What to do...!!
i got this error during rebuild....--->

```
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.androlib.Androl
ibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec command: [aapt, p, --min-
sdk-version, 8, -F, C:\Users\SaMPoR\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL501867114468940568
1.tmp, -I, C:\Users\SaMPoR\apktool\framework\1.apk, -S, C:\Users\SaMPoR\Desktop\
Android New Stuff\apk tool\apktool1.5.1\2\res, -M, C:\Users\SaMPoR\Desktop\Andro
id New Stuff\apk tool\apktool1.5.1\2\AndroidManifest.xml]
        at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResourcesFull(Androlib.java:357)
        at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResources(Androlib.java:282)
        at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:205)
        at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:176)
        at brut.apktool.Main.cmdBuild(Main.java:218)
        at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:74)
Caused by: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not
 exec command: [aapt, p, --min-sdk-version, 8, -F, C:\Users\SaMPoR\AppData\Local
\Temp\APKTOOL5018671144689405681.tmp, -I, C:\Users\SaMPoR\apktool\framework\1.ap
k, -S, C:\Users\SaMPoR\Desktop\Android New Stuff\apk tool\apktool1.5.1\2\res, -M
, C:\Users\SaMPoR\Desktop\Android New Stuff\apk tool\apktool1.5.1\2\AndroidManif
est.xml]
        at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.aaptPackage(AndrolibResources.jav
a:349)
        at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResourcesFull(Androlib.java:335)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec command: [aapt, p, --min-sd
k-version, 8, -F, C:\Users\SaMPoR\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL5018671144689405681.
tmp, -I, C:\Users\SaMPoR\apktool\framework\1.apk, -S, C:\Users\SaMPoR\Desktop\An
droid New Stuff\apk tool\apktool1.5.1\2\res, -M, C:\Users\SaMPoR\Desktop\Android
 New Stuff\apk tool\apktool1.5.1\2\AndroidManifest.xml]
        at brut.util.OS.exec(OS.java:89)
        at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.aaptPackage(AndrolibResources.jav
a:347)
        ... 6 more
```

Update:->
yeah i just changed package name in manifest file so i got this error now i changed My package name in All Xml Files So There is no such error but when i try to install updated apk its close unexpectedly i think (i am not sure) i need to change package name in classes too...if yes how...? b'coz i Don't have original Source code.....!!!

Comment: any updates on this ? I am facing similar issue :(

Comment: yor don't need to go to manifest just select the package you want to change and press F2 . rename  it .. May be it asked for you to import it in inner classes. then it will automatically change it in Manifest

Answer (score -2):

try copying aapt.exe file in sdk>platform-tools to c:\windows